# Saving Values to a database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to make an app for a restaurant. I have set up a local database and have a prepared statement to save a users username and password to enable them to log into the system, but it does not seem to work. The username and passwords are not saving. Below is my code, if anyone has any solutions, i would greatly appreciate it.

```
public class register extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText username, password;
Button registartion;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
}

private Connection getConnection()
{

    String host = "jdbc:mysql://jdbc.fmc.me.uk:3306/db_ben";
    String u = "user_ben";
    String p = "******";
    try
    {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, u, p);
        return con;
    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private boolean registerUser(){

    //Get username
    EditText regUsernameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegUsername);
    String regUsernameStr = regUsernameBox.getText().toString();

    //Get password
    EditText regPasswordBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPassword);
    String regPasswordStr = regPasswordBox.getText().toString();

    System.out.println(regUsernameStr);
    System.out.println(regPasswordStr);

    int i = 0;
    Connection con = getConnection();
    try {
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into users values(?,?)");
        pst.setString(1, regUsernameStr);
        pst.setString(2,regPasswordStr);
        i = pst.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(i>0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public void buttonClick() {
    final Button registerUsers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    registerUsers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            registerUser();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: update your post with what errors you get saying more about your findings on debugging.

Comment: There are no errors, the code just wont save the data to the database as I thought it would do

Answer (score 1):

None of your methods are being called. Your oncreate sets the view for the activity and then does nothing. Hence, you get no errors as there are technically none. You have to set the button click instructions for the button in the create. Your onCreate should look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
     final Button registerUsers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

     registerUsers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             registerUser();
         }
     });
}
```

Now here the button is assigned a variable and then the clicklistener is set to it onCreate. Now when you click the button it would do something.

Comment: When I run this code and test it on the emulator, an error appears saying the emulator has stopped working?

Comment: that's because there is an error...please paste the log cat

Comment: Please mark it answered if it solved the problem mentioned in the query. It would help others in future

Answer (score 1):

iQuote the android references http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)

i also think that you should use asynctask  to do database work to keep your app responsive

onCreate(Bundle) is where you initialize your activity. Most importantly, here you will usually call setContentView(int) with a layout resource defining your UI, and using findViewById(int) to retrieve the widgets in that UI that you need to interact with programmatically.

so it must look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
EditText regUsernameBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegUsername);
EditText regPasswordBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RegPassword);
Button registerUsers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

registerUsers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{  
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        registerUser();
    }
});
}
```